# sed to edit a field in a config script

Tags: bash, sed

It's been quite a while since I've had edit a shell script, so please be patient. I have a script used for a database failover that I'm trying to make more intelligent. One of the lines in it reads something like

```
primary_connection = 'host=10.10.1.129 port=5033'
```

and I need to change the value for the host. The problem is that value could be either an IP address as shown or a name. Being this is part of a shell script, I really need to use sed or another simple and readily available command to change this. Other options like perl or python aren't available on this system. I've tried several different regex patterns but can't seem to get the syntax correct and I get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat file
hello
primary_connection = 'host=10.10.1.129 port=5033'
bye
```

You can use:

```
$ sed -r "s/(primary_connection[ ]*=[ ]*'host=)[^ ]*/\1t/" file
hello
primary_connection = 'host=t port=5033'
bye
```

Or more complex:

```
$ sed -r "s/(primary_connection[ ]*=[ ]*'host[ ]*=)[^ ]*/\1t/" file
hello
primary_connection = 'host=t port=5033'
bye
```

To have in-place editing, add `-i.bak`. This will backup the file to `file.bak` and `file` will then be updated.

Comment: Note that regex class shortcuts like `\s` may not be portable.  For example, this solution does not work on FreeBSD, OSX, HP/UX, Solaris...

Comment: @ghoti true, in fact I firstly started with just spaces instead of `\s`... and now I revoked to that. Thanks!

Comment: Then you get another +1.  :-)  I was thinking I'd assemble an answer with awk or pure bash, but really, sed is better (and *much* shorter) in this case.

Answer (score 2):

One of the down sides with constructs like `sed "s/something/$variable/"` is that if `$variable` contains a slash, your script fails disastrously, and if someone were able to maliciously modify that variable, they could potentially insert code which would be run by your sed script.

Generally, you don't want to use variables that haven't been checked for validity.  So an answer that gives you just the sed-based solution is a start, but is incomplete.

Since you tagged your question with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), here's a solution that runs in bash alone.  It's pretty explicit, so as to avoid any possibility of errors with something as vitally important as database redundancy.

```
#!/bin/bash

# You'd likely get this from $1, or elsewhere...
newhost="10.1.1.1"

# Use "extglob" extended pattern matching...
shopt -s extglob

# Go through each line of the input file...
while read line; do

  # Recognize the important configuration line...
  if [[ "$line" =~ ^primary_connection\ =\  ]]; then

    # Detect the field to change, AND validate our input.
    if [[ "$line" =~ host=[^\ ]+ ]] && [[ "$newhost" =~ ^[a-z0-9.-]+$ ]]; then
      line="${line/host=+([^ ])/host=$newhost}"
    fi

  fi

  # Output the current (possibly modified) line.
  echo "$line"

done < inputfile
```

Output from this script is the input file with the host substituted.  You can probably figure out how to safely move the old file out of the way and copy the new one into place.

Note that we're only allowing alphanumeric, period and hyphen characters in the hostname, which should be sufficient to allow hostnames and IP addresses.

I tested with the following `inputfile`:

```
foo
# primary_connection is a string.
primary_connection = 'host=10.10.1.129 port=5033'
bar
```

Note that because the regex recognizing the "important configuration line" is anchored with a carat, we don't risk changing lines that are comments.  If you choose a `sed` based answer, you should consider using a similar anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak "/primary_connection/s/\(host=\)[^[:blank:]]*/\1$new_host_name/" file
```

Comment: Alas, not really.  The OP hasn't specified, so you can't assume that there will be no `host=` strings elsewhere in the input file.  Always be explicit.

Comment: @ghoti: ok I made it explicit to make it safer.